# How to activate compression for Azure Front Door routes using Bicep?

Tags: azure, compression, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I am using Azure Front Door Standard/Premium and have already manually enabled compression for my UI routes via Azure Portal. I wanted to map this configuration as IaC with Bicep. However, there was no proper documentation on how to do this. My attempts:

1. I checked the [Azure Bicep templates for Azure Front Door routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.cdn/2020-09-01/profiles/afdendpoints/routes?tabs=bicep). Here I found a reference to a property `compressionSettings: any()`, whose usage was not further specified.
2. My next approach was to export the manual configuration in the portal via "Export template" as ARM and then compile it to Bicep. However, the `compressionSettings` property always kept the value `{}`. If I deploy my bicep template with the value `compressionSettings: {}`, then the compression in the portal remains disabled.

So how can I enable compression for Azure Front Door using Bicep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by manually searching in azure-quickstart-templates. At the bottom of the page: [Microsoft.Cdn profiles/afdEndpoints/routes 2020-09-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.cdn/2020-09-01/profiles/afdendpoints/routes?tabs=bicep), I found the template [Front Door Standard/Premium](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.network/front-door-standard-premium). After analyzing the `main.bicep` file here, the compression settings must be set as follows:

```
compressionSettings: {
   contentTypesToCompress: [
     'application/javascript'
     'application/json'
     'font/woff'
     'font/woff2'
     'image/svg+xml'
     'image/x-icon'
     'text/css'
     'text/html'
   ]
   isCompressionEnabled: true
}
```

Within a section of my entire code it then looks like this:

```
var contentTypesToCompress = [
  'application/javascript'
  'application/json'
  'font/woff'
  'font/woff2'
  'image/svg+xml'
  'image/x-icon'
  'text/css'
  'text/html'
]

resource profile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2020-09-01' = {
  name: 'frontDoor'
  location: 'global'
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_AzureFrontDoor'
  }
  tags: tags
}

resource endpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2020-09-01' = {
  parent: profile
  name: 'endpoint'
  location: 'Global'
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    originResponseTimeoutSeconds: 60
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource route 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints/routes@2020-09-01' = {
  parent: endpoint
  name: 'route'
  properties: {
    queryStringCachingBehavior: 'IgnoreQueryString'
    compressionSettings: {
      contentTypesToCompress: contentTypesToCompress
      isCompressionEnabled: true
    }
    ...
  }
  dependsOn: [
    profile
  ]
}
```

Since this has not really been documented anywhere so far, I thought it would be useful to share this here in [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).